# CSS strange behavior for background-position

Tags: css, background-position

I have this CSS to show a water mark inside a div:

```
background-image: url("../Images/Watermark02.png") !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: right bottom;
```

the behavior is shown in the below image, can somebody help me and tell me what is missing to get it to work on Chrome just like FF?

[image]

Comment: Please provide some more code.

Comment: Really can you setup a http://jsbin.com demo? I bet there will be no issues - which might lead you to some conclusions. Often, when you sample your issue you realize what actually was.

Comment: @ZachSaucier exactly. fixed. Too much coffee and my fingers just fly...

Comment: thanks I played with the codeon jsbin.com and found that removing fixed would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by removing **background-attachment: fixed**. The "fixed" value is relative to the screen, not the  you have the background image inside of. Granted it's possible this is due to something else, but I will need to see the rest of your CSS/HTML.

```
background-attachment: fixed; /* Remove this */
```

I've set up a jsfiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/HkBh4/